# how to match array with database table?

Tags: php

I want to show calender as what the data in a particular month it shows all data in that month.

Suppose, I have data in my database as..

```
Jan=124;   Jan=243;   Jan=354
Feb=978;  Feb=765;   Feb=756;
```

It can be as:

```
Jan,2013
   124
   243
   354

Feb,2013
   978
   765
   756
```

I have did this code:

```
<?php
$q2="select * from  calendar";
$res2=mysql_query($q2);
$row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($res2);
$mnth = array('Jan','Feb');
$j= count($mnth);
for ($i=0; $i<= $j; $i++){
    if($row2['month']=='June'){ 
        ?><tr><td><?php 
        echo $row2['month']; ?> , <?php echo $row2['year']; 
        ?></td></tr><tbody><div><?php

        include("connection.php");
        $q1="select * from  calendar";
        $res=mysql_query($q1);

        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
            ?><tr><td><?php 
            echo $row['dates']; 
            ?></td></tr></tbody></div><?php 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please format your code so that it is readable? Thank you! Also, what does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: Don't use `mysql_` functions - they are deprecated.  Switch to `mysqli_` or PDO.

Comment: What is your table structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would reconsider breaking out of PHP every time you need to print HTML tags. It makes your code hard to read.

Also, you're doing a query within a loop, which is a bad idea, and looks completely unnecessary for your problem.

You also have an opening `<tbody>` tag in your loop with no closing `</tbody>` tag.

And, as @AleksG mentioned in the comments, you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated. I recommend switching to PDO.

So on to the answer...

Assuming your table structure looks like this:

```
+-------+------+-------+
| month | year | dates |
+-------+------+-------+
| Jan   | 2013 | 124   |
| Jan   | 2013 | 243   |
| Jan   | 2013 | 354   |
| Feb   | 2013 | 978   |
| Feb   | 2013 | 765   |
| Feb   | 2013 | 756   |
+-------+------+-------+
```

Based on your question title, this will put the values into an array, with the keys being the month and year, and the values being the numeric "dates" field:

```
// replace the below line with your mysql connection string
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$result = $dbh->query('
    SELECT month, year, dates FROM calendar ORDER BY year, month
');

$mnth = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $key = $row['month'] .','. $row['year']; // e.g. 'Jan,2013'
    // push the new value. The inner array will be created automatically
    $mnth[$key][] = $row['dates'];
}

print_r($mnth);
/* will look like this:
Array(
    [Jan,2013] => Array(
        [0] => 124,
        [1] => 243,
        [2] => 354
    ),
    [Feb,2013] => Array(
        [0] => 978,
        [1] => 765,
        [2] => 756
    )
) */
```

But based on your code, it looks like you want to output this as an HTML table. So here's how you could do that. The query is the same, so this just replaces the loop:

```
echo '<table>';
$current = '';
foreach ($result as $row) {
    // check to see if we've switched to a new month/year
    $next = $row['month'] .','. $row['year'];
    if ($current != $next) {
        // if we have moved to a new month/year, print a new header row
        echo '<tr><th>'. $next .'</th></tr>';
        // and update $current
        $current = $next;
    }

    echo '<tr><td>'. $row['dates'] .'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Good answer! Although personal opinion, I would do: `$current = ($current != sprintf('%s,%d', $row['month'], $row['year'])) ? $row['month'] : $row['year'];` :)

Comment: @Jimbo: That would assign `$row['month']` to `$current` if it is equal, or `$row['year']` to `$current` if it is not equal. But what's wrong with a simple concatenation? Is there an advantage I'm unaware of in using `sprintf`? And I tend to avoid ternaries...they can be difficult to follow.

Comment: No of course not, hence why it's just opinion. Not sure why, but I *love* `sprintf()` and ternaries. Maybe I've become a bit of a code masochist over the years...